# Mining All Tweets and Retweets from A Specified User's Timeline Using Tweepy

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

I'm trying to mine every single tweet on the WomensMarch's Twitter timeline.

I've been trying to use Tweepy and Python 3.x, but I can't seem to mine more than 3219 tweets back. Is there any way to mine /every/ tweet that a specified user on Twitter has ever retweeted or tweeted since the creation of their account?

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
import pandas as pd
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
import time 

consumer_key = "--"
consumer_secret = "--"
access_token = "--"
access_secret = "--"

authHandler = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
authHandler.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
twitterAPI = tweepy.API(authHandler, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

womensMarchTwitter = twitterAPI.get_user('womensmarch')
minedTwitterDataFrom_womensMarchTwitter = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Tweet Text", "Tweet Created On"])

def MineTimelineData(idToMine):
    cursor = tweepy.Cursor(twitterAPI.user_timeline, id=idToMine)
    while(tweepy.Cursor(twitterAPI.user_timeline).items() != None):
        try:
            for page in cursor.pages():
                for tweet in page:
                    yield tweet
        except tweepy.RateLimitError:
            print("Rate limit reached! Waiting 15 minutes...")
            time.sleep(60 * 15) #wait 15 minutes (900 seconds)

minedData = MineTimelineData(womensMarchTwitter.id)

numberOfTweetsMined = 0
for tweet in minedData:
    print(tweet.text)
    print("Posted on: ", tweet.created_at)
    minedTwitterDataFrom_womensMarchTwitter.loc[numberOfTweetsMined, "Tweet Text"] = tweet.text
    minedTwitterDataFrom_womensMarchTwitter.loc[numberOfTweetsMined, "Tweet Created On"] = tweet.created_at
    numberOfTweetsMined = numberOfTweetsMined + 1

minedTwitterDataFrom_womensMarchTwitter.to_csv(r"PATH") 
print(numberOfTweetsMined)
print("\n \n \n Finished Mining Tweets!")
```

Comment: Not a big deal, but terminology wise, it sounds like you're trying to 'fetch'. 'Mining' typically refers to finding some kind of insight in the data, like what emotions are being expressed. :)

Comment: @Chet, ah, I didn't know that, actually. Thanks for the information! :D

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Twitter API docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline.html) the most records you can return at once using `user_timeline` is going to be 3,200.

From the docs:

> This method can only return up to 3,200 of a user’s most recent Tweets. Native retweets of other statuses by the user is included in this total, regardless of whether `include_rts` is set to `false` when requesting this resource.

I'm honestly not sure how you got those extra 19 tweets, but this is definitely part of the spec.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the information about user_timeline! Do you know of an API method I can use to get all tweets and retweets from a user?

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can't do that as a third party - you would have to have the user download all of their tweets and then upload them to your service.